# Selenium Webdriver does not load the entire page

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to load the URL: (https://shop.countdown.co.nz/shop/browse/beer-wine) using selenium webdriver, but despite waiting for jquery to load and ajax to finish, the entire webpage does not get loaded! I am new to WebDriver, so if someone could load this page and post the code, I would appreciate that. The webpage does get loaded inside Chrome and I can see a lot of content inside the tag .

Here is my newbie code that I used to load this page:

```
public static void waitForAjaxToFinish(WebDriver driver) {

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10000);
    wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {

        public Boolean apply(WebDriver wdriver) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return jQuery.active == 0").equals(true);
        }

    });
}
public static void waitForJQueryToBeActive(WebDriver driver) {
    Boolean isJqueryUsed = (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
            .executeScript("return (typeof(jQuery) != 'undefined')");
    if (isJqueryUsed) {
        while (true) {
            // JavaScript test to verify jQuery is active or not
            Boolean ajaxIsComplete = (Boolean) (((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
                    .executeScript("return jQuery.active == 0"));
            if (ajaxIsComplete)
                break;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void useSelenium() throws Exception {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    waitForAjaxToFinish(driver);
    waitForJQueryToBeActive(driver);
    try {
        driver.get(COUNTDOWN_URL_MAIN);
        System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
    } finally {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: So you first open the browser with `new ChromeDriver()`, then you have two custom waits, and **only after that** you open the page with `driver.get...`? That seems out of order.

Comment: Should I be adding the waits after the get() call?

Comment: I added those calls after driver.get() and it worked! Thank you, Siking!